# What type of encoding is this JSON encoded with

Tags: json, encoding, decoding

```
U2FsdGVkX18m5Rpkkt39bvho5uYAfKOucpyZBocs10t9ATuCY/uqa8iFoQTraeJCRNlAUk6DK5Hj5UJL4ZKcqAm9/MWPHSrtJiIQSu7/dvCvG1MvwqtvQJ45Zgg536P1FEgoKw4aFhNQ0PV8V9ng6TMjnnEB8JAsQcDY+R5GPdnJRorxdW9J3pTJvrRUeWo7JWzP53uvu4MH6bYKcl0VdPcwiOTHZOlAzxWk65oe0jzXjZ24zqMPQJEx51ctDnz0HvYwt4F6+7dcO/
```

This should be a json object but it's encoded and I don't know what type of encoding is this

Comment: Try https://www.base64decode.org/ and you see the `Salted__` prefix [almost certainly means this either is the output of the openssl enc command or something designed to be compatible with it](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/124333/160539).

Answer (score 0):

This string is not in JSON format, because it lacks at least a pair of curly brackets `{}` and/or a pair of braces `[]`.

Go to https://www.base64decode.org/ => set the Source Character set to 'AUTO-DETECT' and observe that the decoded string starts with: `Salted__`.

This string is encoded (and encrypted for that matter) in OpenSSL salted format: http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/OpenSSL_salted_format